# PrimeFaces TabView dynamic

Tags: primefaces

Estou com problema ao utilizar o dynamic="false" no p:tabview do Primefaces. Se informo como dynamic="true" tudo funciona normal, porém se informo false que é minha necessidade, ao clicar no botão ele enviar a tela, não efetua as validações e duplica o bloco de botões como na imagem abaixo.

Este é o comportamento:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPzX3.png

Comment: Mostre um trecho do código que vc está usando.

Comment: Foi resolvido. Agradeço a atenção.